# A code in Wordpress footer created by dFactory cookie plugins

Tags: wordpress, cookies

I'm not a technical shark which is why I hope one of you can help me.

I installed a cookie by dFacotory to my Wordpress page, and now I get a code in my footer.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isYsf.png)

I dont know how to remove it, and when I inspect the element and track the code I get following code;

```
<body class="home page-template-default page page-id-14 logged-in admin-bar full-width    
 header-shadow bg-fill lightbox 
nav-dropdown-has-arrow customize-support 
cookies-set cookies-accepted" data-gr-c-s-loaded="true">…</body>
```

Can anybody help me? (BTW I need to put some spaces between the code, so it would be shown as a code, don't know if I did it correct)

Comment: Hi, I am reviewing your post. You should add images directly, since web-addresses can change. It also makes it easier for the SO community to reproduce your query.

Comment: Just uploaded the picture, did it work?